# Ubuntu 16/18 bond при установке ОС

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

Ситуация: требуется переустановить сервер, у которого сетевые интерфейсы собраны в bond.  Установка осуществляется через IPMI.

Проблема: после загрузки образа OS (mini) установка останавливается на этапе получения ip, так как роутере bond не разбирался.(указывать ip в ручную нет смысла). а разбирать bound на роутере нет возможности.

Вопрос: Как можно активировать bound интерфейс на этапе установке ОС?

Возможно вопрос можно перефразировать: как встроить в установочный образ модуль bond который будет загружен или автоматом или через доступный шел с помощью команды modprobe?

Comment: Bound это `bond`? Что за OS ставите, в которой нельзя отключить все интерфейсы кроме одного?

Comment: Спасибо, ошибся - речь о bond. Вопрос не в устанавливаемой ОС (ubuntu). а в роутере. при установке новой ОС все интерфейсы и так по одному, а нужно как раз объеденить их - чтобы иметь возможность скачать недостающие пакеты и установить сервер в минимальной конфигурации

Comment: Я видимо не совсем понимаю что Вы пытаетесь сделать. Вот допустим существуют некие роутер и сервер. Они соединены между друг другом 4-мя проводами витой пары. Со стороны роутера из этих четырёх портов собран bond (или port-channel или как он на этом роутере называется). Так вот мой вопрос: когда Вы по ipmi монтируете live-cd ubuntu (например), в чём сложность выключить на этапе настройки сети три линка, оставив активным только один. Разве в таком случае у Вас не будет L3-коннективности с роутером? Сервер не сможет получить адрес по dhcp (или что там у Вас)?

Comment: совершенно верно. роутер не знает что bond разобран - и не обрабатывает пакеты от новой ОС. хотя, возможно он принимает пакеты по одному интерфейсу, но ответы отправляет по другому - который не настроен.

Comment: Дык как он такое может делать, если когда вы отключите интерфейсы со стороны сервера `ip l s ethN down` они перестанут быть активны на роутере? Роутер _обязан_ в этом случае выкинуть их из агрегированного канала, иначе он работает некорректно, нет fault tolerance. Зачем нужен такой агрегат/bond, где в случае падения одного линка - деградирует весь сервис?

Comment: всё зависит от режима работы bond. в данном случае для получения большей пропускной способности используется 4й, который требует настройки/поддержки не только в ОС но и в коммутаторе

Comment: Всё ясно. Ну, я б на Вашем месте просто перенастроил на balance-xor, например. Либо со стороны роутера/коммутатора на время установки ОС вырубил лишние линки ^_^

Comment: Ещё одна небольшая корректива, если Вы позволите. Когда Вы говорите "4й режим работы" - Вы подразумеваете LAG 802.3ad ? Если да, то как я и говорил раньше, он вполне себе поддерживает fault tolerance, а это значит что при выходе из строя линка - последний "выбрасывается" из агрегата. Пруф, например, тут http://www.ieee802.org/3/hssg/public/apr07/frazier_01_0407.pdf или в wiki (Агрегирование каналов). По сему уточню, Вы точно со стороны сервера порты пробовали вырубать? Если пробовали и ничего не получилось - либо что-то не так делаете, либо у разрабов OS коммутатора своеобразное понимание LAG.

Comment: @nobody, я бы вполне допускал ситуацию, при которой роутер настроен считать все физические интерфейсы LAG'а дохлыми по той причине, что сосед не отвечает на LACPDU. И не переходит в fallback режим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению единственным вариантом оказалось использование образа live-server. Он позволяет собрать bond прямо в процессе установки.

Конфигурация **mini** сильно урезанная, и не смотря на то что сам модуль bonding в ней присутствует, собрать bond интерфейс не получится, так как нет пакетов  **ifenslave** или **netplan**

При попытке использовать доступный ip:

```
ip link set eth0 master bond0:
```

т.е при попытке указать master устройство вываливается в ошибку:

```
bond ip ether dev is duplicate or master is garbage
```

Answer (score 0):

Собрать для установочного ядра модуль `bonding.ko` и попробовать подсунуть его машине на USB-флешке? Если не получится, то в инсталляционный образ.

И дальше как велит документация:

```
modprobe bonding mode=<ваш режим> miimon=100
ifconfig bond0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ip link set eth0 master bond0
ip link set eth1 master bond0
```